# Xcode 8.1 Unable to delete scene -> lock symbol?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I am not able to delete a scene (complete view controller) from the canvas as I did it 1000 times before? I am marking the view controller scene and press the delete button. Normally the scene should be delete from the project. But with that scene a lock symbol appears in the middle of the screen and nothing happens?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to clean your project or restart Xcode.

(1) Open your Storyboard and choose your UIViewController.
(2) Open the Utility Panel on the upper right hand of the Xcode window and choose the Identity Inspector.
(3) Make sure that the 'Locked' status of your UIViewController is 'Inherited'.
(4) Try again to delete your UIViewController.

[Check this image for further explanations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq1eI.png)

I hope this helped.

Comment: You saved my day! There was one element an uibutton which had the Lock property set to "All Properties".